# Trim data from JSON that doesn't include defined array?

Tags: php, json

There's JSON data with `Offers`

```
foreach($json['offers'] as $offer)
```

Every offer has data that contains country

```
"countries":[{"name":"United States","code":"US"}]
```

How do I remove all the offers if they dont include for example `"US"`?

As far as I understand I should use `array_map` right? But how do I tell it to remove those that doesn't include value instead of those who does include value I define?

Comment: `array_map()` is for changing (all) data. You want `array_filter()`.

Comment: as @Dormilich you should use array_filter - var_dump(array_filter($offers, function($offer) { return ('US' === $offer['countries'][0]['code'] ?? null); }));

Comment: Possible duplicate of [array\_filter with assoc array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199496/array-filter-with-assoc-array)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `array_filter()`

```
$json['offers'] = array_filter($json['offers'], function($item){
    return $item['countries'][0]['code'] == "US";
});
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/bUCTZ)

Answer (score 0):

If I don't misunderstood your question, then simple `array_filter()` will do the trick for you.

```
<?php

$json = '[{"countries":[{"name":"United States","code":"US"}]},{"countries":[{"name":"United Kingdom","code":"UK"}]},{"countries":[{"name":"Canada","code":"CA"}]}]';
$decode = json_decode($json,1);
$new = array_filter($decode, function ($var) {
    return ($var['countries'][0]['code'] != 'US');
});
print_r($new);
?>
```

**DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/LtPEl

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for answers, but I've did it in another way..

```
$salys2 = array("US");      
$salys = array_map('trim', $salys2);    


if (!in_array($offer['countries'][0]['code'], $salys)) {

    // skipping
    continue;
}
```

Could someone explain me why are we keeping `[0]` between countries and code?