# PHP array_filter in multidimensional associative array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array, array-filter

I need to find the value for a key by searching for another value within the same array of a multidimensional array.

This is the given array:

```
<?php 

$users = array(

    "userA" => array(
                "email" => "userA@email.com",
                "language" => "en",
            ),

    "userB" => array(
                "email" => "userB@email.com",
                "language" => "de",
            ),

    "userC" => array(
                "email" => "userC@email.com",
                "language" => "it",
            ),

);

?>
```

Example:
I want to input...

```
$lang = 'de';
```

...and get the value for "email" of that same item. So in this case it should output:

```
userB@email.com
```

The languages are unique, so there will only be one possible match.

If this already might be asked, I apologize, but I couldn't find anything with that structure and this search condition.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) for this -

```
// Generate array with language as key
$new = array_column($users, 'email', 'language');
// access array value (email) by language
echo $new['de'];
```

**Output**

```
userB@email.com
```

Answer (score 0):

This might be difficult to achieve with `array_filter`, but you could look at other alternatives, like a `foreach` loop and `array_push`

```
$filtered = [];

foreach($users as $key => $value) {
    if($value['language'] == 'de') {
        array_push($filtered, [$key => $value]);
    }
}
```

See [array_filter with assoc array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6199496/array-filter-with-assoc-array)

Answer (score 0):

There is one recursive way to achieve this,

```
function recursive_array_search($needle,$haystack) {
    foreach($haystack as $key=>$value) {
        $current_key=$key;
        if($needle===$value OR (is_array($value) && recursive_array_search($needle,$value) !== false)) {
            return $current_key;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
// searching 'de' and getting all array or specific value by key. Its multipurpose method.
$temp = $users[recursive_array_search('de', $users)]['email']; 
print_r($temp);
```

Ref [Link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php#91365).

([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/274480b9f83d4820f491f7702718d411f5ebd5da))